# Display PercentDone UIProgressView in UiLabel

Tags: uilabel, uiprogressview

I have a button connected to a UiProgressView, has only the function to count the clicks on the button ... I need to show the percentage of completion in a UILabel .. Can you tell me which method is better?

To make you understand the function I show you the code of the IBAction

```
- (IBAction)FFAddCFU:(id)sender {
if (FFVariabileNumerica_CFU >= 30)
return;
FFVariabileNumerica_CFU++ ;
[FFCFULabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", FFVariabileNumerica_CFU]];

if(FFProgressBar.progress == 0.50 || FFProgressBar.progress == 0.77 ){
[ FFProgressBar setProgress : FFProgressBar.progress +0.25 ];

} else {
if (FFProgressBar.progress > 0.76) {
[ FFProgressBar setProgress : FFProgressBar.progress +0.25 ]; }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this in a small project of mine for a custom progress view. It can be found at [lightdesign/LDProgressView](https://github.com/lightdesign/LDProgressView). You can take a look at the file `LDProgressView.m` for how I've done this.

Here's the relevant line:

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f%%", self.progress*100];
```

This line takes the progress value which is between `0.0` and `1.0` and multiplies it by `100` and then inserts the number up to the whole number (`.0` in the format string) with a percentage at the end (`%%` in the format string).

Also, if you don't want to manually calculate the percentage, feel free to use the open source control I've made.

Comment: Hello and thank you very much for your response ... I tried everything today to understand the operation of your LDProgressView, but unfortunately I'm still a newbie: (((it was not easy to understand .. It 'a nice code: P ... I noticed the implementation of the percentage but I could not to understand how it can be implemented in a Label with NSString, I've noticed that you've implemented through the use of the control segment. Excuse me for my bad english, i'm italian

Comment: I've updated my answer. I hope it helps you understand what I'm doing in `LDProgressView`. BTW, I also have a bit of italian blood in me, but I don't know the language at all :-).

Comment: Christian Works great! Thank you so much! .... Great Italian blood! : D
Now everything works I have only problems with IBAction because if I push a button gives me 75% if they push me another 77% .. I had to do this because I wanted the progress advancing only once for every button and every time I click no matter which button ... That 'sa bit difficult because I tired the brain: D to find the right situation.  When push a button and get to 75% and if I always push the same button, the progress does not advance forward but only if I push another button other ... This is what I wanted to do